# Calculate RGB Int from Color in C#

Tags: c#, colors

I'd like to reproduce what [this site](https://www.shodor.org/stella2java/rgbint.html) does in C#

This is what I tried:

```cs
Color whiteColor = Color.White;
int intWhiteColor = whiteColor.ToArgb();
```

This is what I obtained: `-1`

This is what I was expecting: `16777215`

I tried searching for almost everything I could think of, but couldn't end up finding what I wanted.

This has an high chance of being a duplicate and I am truely sorry, please link me it if so.

Comment: `int intColor = (redColor.R << 16) | (redColor.G << 8) | (redColor.B);`

Comment: [result is -65536](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DKDfgx) which is expected value (0xffff0000)

Comment: @Selvin Expected value is ``16777215``

Comment: Nice, making use of shift operators... `public static uint MyColorToUInt(Color color)
{
      return (uint)((color.A << 24) | (color.R << 16) |
                    (color.G << 8)  | (color.B << 0));
}`

Comment: [16711680 not  16777215](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5alGYQ) 16777215 is white

Comment: I did name my variable ``redColor`` when it was ``Color.White`` ... My bad, it's 2 AM.

Comment: The System.Drawing namespace has a [ColorTranslator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colortranslator?view=netframework-4.8) class.  `ColorTranslator.ToWin32(...`

Comment: @LarsTech Actually outputs a blue color when using ``Color.Red`` ...

Comment: How did you use it?  `Color.Translator.ToWin32(Color.Red)` returns 255.

Comment: @LarsTech Not what I am asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple *bit arithmetics* will do:

```
 int intColor = (redColor.R << 16) | (redColor.G << 8) | (redColor.B);
```

please, note, that `Color.Red` has `R = 255; G = 0; B = 0` (pure **Red** color) and thus

```
 int intColor == 16711680
```

When `Color.White` has `R = 255; G = 255; B = 255` and thus

```
 int intColor == 16777215
```

Comment: I'd much rather use the `R`, `G`, and `B` properties of the `Color` object. You have no guarantee that, after calling `ToArgb()`, you'll get the bytes in that order. `R`, `G` and `B` give you guarantees instead. That's the whole point of OOP.

Comment: @Simore: I'm sorry, don't follow you: `Color redColor` is of type `Color` I get `R`, `G` and `B` properties of it (which are of type `byte`) and make a final `int intColor`. For sure I don't try to *mask* `intColor` (which is a bad idea, as you've put it) - `(intColor & 0xFF) << 16...`

Comment: Sorry, you are right (downvote removed): I totally misread your answer!

Answer (score 0):

`ToArgb()` returns a 32-bit integer, i.e., 4 bytes, in which each byte corresponds to Alpha, Red, Green and Blue. So, for "red", it would be

```
FF FF 00 00
```

which translates to decimal -65,536 (I'm not sure why you got -1). What you want is something along these lines:

```
string hexcode = string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", redColor.R, redColor.G, redColor.B);
```